# Hibernate mapping

Tags: hibernate

There are two objects, parent and child
Both parent and child implement colour
Child and Parent is mapped by one to many relationship.
However, only parent map to colour column, where colour column only exists on parent table.
Is it possible to map child colour to parent colour via hibernate mapping?

PARENT TABLE
id colour

CHID TABLE
id parent_id

So I can use following within hibernate “child c where c.colour” without use of alias.
If possible, please provide me some examples, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite the solution you were asking for, but why not implement the `getColour` method in `Child` as:

```
public Color getColor() { return this.parent.getColor(); }
```

and use:

```
Child c where c.parent.color = ?
```

in the HQL?

That way, the users of your domain objects will have a `getColor()` method on the `Child` class, which it really gets from its `parent` (as is implemented in the DB). You can hide this indirection inside the DAO layer (which is where the HQL queries are). You can even make the `color` member of `Parent` class `private` and implement `Child.getColor()` using reflection. :-)